# In active/passivebwhen to avoid by + subject in the passive form

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

She ordered the family to be shifted.

1. The family were ordered to be shifted **by her**.
2. The family were ordered to be shifted.

My query in this question is:
Out of the two passive forms which one should be chosen?
 As per format first should be the correct one because **by + subject** is the actual format. But the answer to this question is 2nd option.
We avoid **by + subject**  only in those cases where subject is generally a universal fact such as **by police**.

Secondly **family** is a single entity so we should be using **was** rather than **were**.

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

There is no grammatical or semantic rule. The governing factor is pragmatic: you omit the agent of the action if it is unnecessary to the meaning you are trying to communicate. Some examples:

- You omit the agent because your hearers can supply it from their knowledge of the world or the circumstances ... *For instance, if you say that somebody was given a parking ticket you don't generally need to add that the ticket was written by a meter maid or traffic cop*.
- You omit the agent because it's not important to your discussion ... *For instance, if you are primarily concerned to tell people that a friend was hit in a traffic accident, it's probably not important to tell them who was driving the car that hit her*.
- You omit the agent because you want to suppress the involvement of the agent ... *For instance, a company may admit that "mistakes were made", without openly acknowledging that it was the company or company employees who made the mistakes*.
- You omit the agent because you don't know who it is.